# Mutable variable tied to class, not object

Tags: c++, class, attributes

Let's say I have a simple `class` with a `write` method that only needs to output the class attributes. Among those is a mutable variable called `counter`. Counter shall be incremented every time method `write` is called.

The problem is, `counter` is tied to a class, not specific object. If I have two objects of the same type, and if I call `write` 3 times on the first, but zero on the second, counter will have the same value for both. How can this be fixed? I'm guessing it has something to do with constructors.

```
class SomeClass
{
    double x;
    mutable int counter;

    public:
        double write()
        { 
            return x; 
            ++counter;
        }

        int counterValue()
        {
            return counter;
        }
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass c1, c2;
    c1.write(); 
    c1.write(); 
    c1.write();
    c1.counterValue(); 
    c2.counterValue();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT: 3 3

Comment: Your code does not compile. Post real code that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile after the edit. Have you even tried to compile your code? Post real code that you have tested and exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: It's just a small portion of the code, it does compile now.

Comment: It doesn't output anything however. Nor does it actually ever increment `counter`. You didn't verify your code reproduces the problem you asked about, read about creating a [mcve].

Comment: @MelvinBrooks : Why would the counter increment when the method `write` returns x before the increment ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar The OP has probably misinterpreted the result of undefined behavior due to uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a constructor for your class, that initializes member variables.  E.g.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private:
        double x;
        mutable int counter;

    public:
        SomeClass()
        :   x(0),
            counter(0)
        {
        }

        ...

};
```

Also, `write()` should increment `counter` before returning, so

```
    double write()
    {
        ++counter;
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't count separately for each object,

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable at this stage. As seen in all those comments, the OP stubbornly refuses to create and post an MCVE to exhibit and reproduce the OP's claimed observation. All attempts to help is therefore futile.